# Proper Flow to redirect user to the App store?

Tags: redirect

What's the proper user flow to redirect user to App Store?
We just launched our Android and iOS app.

We used to have a landing page with an intro paragraph describing the app, but now we're wanting to just automatically redirect a visitor to either the App Store or the Play Store depending on their device.

Would that be considered an incorrect user experience?

**For Example**: if they type in on their mobile browser, `www.mysite.com`, it'll automatically redirect them to the App Store or Play Store without landing on `www.mysite.com` at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Ran.dy! Can you clarify your question a bit? Who are your users? What's the context? What are you optimizing for or hoping to achieve? What do you mean by "an incorrect user experience"?

Comment: Is there nothing of value on your site? If the domain is just a landing page to advertise an app, then do that. If you have content, is there any reason not to provide it on the site?

Comment: @plainclothes  Correct, there is nothing of "real" value to the landing page aside from describing what the app is and what the app does.  There's no other content on our domain, nor a working web application to its native app equivalent.

Comment: Makes sense. I added an answer addressing your scenario.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  Thanks!  We will *not* go with the autoredirect route.

Answer (score 3):

I would be weary of a domain redirecting me to the app store straight away as I would feel like I have less control over the end to end experience. Also how do I know that the app I am being redirected to is the correct one and not a malicious one?

A simple landing page with links to both the App Store and Play Store is better because then the user knows exactly where they are going when they tap the store link, it helps to build trust with the user.

Comment: They clicked / typed in a URL because they wanted to go to a site or a web app. Don't send them to a marketplace without their consent.

Answer (score 1):

## Let the user decide

As I mentioned in a comment, the user chose to visit you in-browser — respect that decision. Users like to know what's happening. Being redirected without warning or the option to intervene is rarely a good experience.

## Don’t waste an opportunity

Tell a compelling story beyond user reviews and app store blurbs. Send a message you can control. Pack the page with reasons to head to the app marketplace of their choice. And give search engines something to consume.

Here’s a reference pattern from the hot newish property: [Vurb mobile search](http://vurb.com/).

[image]

And a similar idea for a desktop app from the new UI industry darling, [Bohemian’s Sketch.app](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/).

[image: Bohemian Coding's Sketch.app lander]

Comment: I cannot agree strongly enough.  This is like a shoe store where, if you glance in the window, a sales assistant comes outside, hands you a pair of shoes and holds out a credit card reader.  If you do this, I will assume your app is some sleazy free-to-play junk that's not worth space on my home screen, and I am quite serious when I say that this alone would rule out any chance of me installing it.